# Printing result of Caesar cipher program

Tags: c

I'm trying to add `"Encrypted message: "` before the encrypted message is printed.

When I put the `printf` statement inside the "while" loop, I get something along the lines of:
`AEncrypred message: BEncrypted message: CEncrypted message:` etc.

If I try and put the `printf` statement outside the loop, nothing prints.

Is there a way to print `"Encrypted message: "` before the result while still using `putchar();` ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>   

char encrypt(char in, int key) 
{
    if (isalpha(in)) 
    {  
        if (isupper(in)) 
        {
            return (((in-'A') + key) % 26) + 'A';
        }
        else 
        {
            return (((in-'a') + key) % 26) + 'a';
        }
    }
    else return in;
}

int main()
{
    int key;
    char ch, res;

    printf("Enter shift amount (1-25):\n");
    scanf("%d", &key);

    printf("Enter message to be encrypted:\n");
    getchar();

    while (ch != '\n') 
    {
        ch = getchar();
        res = encrypt(ch, key);
        putchar(res);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: build a char array and print it with `printf`

Comment: If you're reading a single char and then writing a single char, you can't output anything before the output. You'd end up with exactly the output you're getting. A better method would be to accept *all* of the input first, print your message, and then print the encrypted output all at once, rather than processing a single character at a time.

Comment: The assignment asks: 1. You must use getchar() to input characters and putchar() to output characters.
2. Since you do not know the length of the message, you cannot store it in an array. You should input, encrypt and output one character at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char encrypt(char in, int key)
{
    if (isalpha(in))
    {
        if (isupper(in))
        {
            return (((in-'A') + key) % 26) + 'A';
        }
        else
        {
            return (((in-'a') + key) % 26) + 'a';
        }
    }
    else return in;
}

int main()
{
    int key;
    char ch, res;
    int checksum = 1;

    printf("Enter shift amount (1-25):\n");
    scanf("%d", &key);

    printf("Enter message to be encrypted:\n");
    getchar();

    while (ch != '\n')
    {
        ch = getchar();
        res = encrypt(ch, key);
        if(checksum) { checksum = 0; printf("Encrypted message: "); }
        putchar(res);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would use that way. If you don't like it.. let me know.
I just solved it on a way that won't violate your code structure.

---

Your problem is putting the `printf` statement inside a loop. The loop will parse your `printf` statelement ? times , until `ch` equals new line. To prevent that you can use a variable outside the scope, initialized with a value for example `1`. To parse the `printf` statement once you do a condition if that variable equals its number and then assign 0 or another number to it. So in the next time the `printf` has to be parsed, it won't go, because the condition will be false.